# How to make binary data as an output?

Tags: python, binary-data

I need to do PractRand tests. And it requires:

"PractRand supports testing ONLY on packed binary data as input. You can not give it ASCII 0s and 1s or ASCII hex or anything else that doesn't have 8 random bits per byte."

http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/Tests_overview.txt

I have 128-bit numbers and I need to export it to antoher program like that:

python3 mygenerator.py | ./RNG_test stdin

Then PractRand can do the tests.

This:

```
binary = bin(number)[2:].zfill(128)
print(binary,end='')
```

Doesn't work. This:

```
split=[(number >> x) & 0xFFFFFFFF for x in reversed(range(0, 128, 32))]

binary = struct.pack('qqqq', split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3])

print(binary,end='')
```

Doesn't work (I'm splitting number, beacuse 'q' format is 32-bit). Is it even possible to output packed binary data and not ASCII 0s and 1s or ASCII hex or anything else that doesn't have 8 random bits per byte in Python? I really doubt it, although I know it can be done in C++.

Comment: I think print only works with string datatypes. Have you tried using sys.stdout ?
`sys.stdout.write(binary)` looks good to me

Comment: @MathisGerma I have error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes. And with "binary = bin(number)[2:].zfill(128)" it still doesn't work properly. I mean generator which passes all test in C++, doesn't pass in Python (so I assume it has to be a problem with data format, PractRand read it as ASCII "1" and "0" or something).

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution lies [In this note of python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr)

> To write or read binary data from/to the standard streams, use the underlying binary buffer object. For example, to write bytes to stdout, use **sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc')**.

Comment: How to use it? If I write sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'binary') or sys.stdout.buffer.write(binary) it still doesn't work. I mean tests still fails, so again probably format is wrong.